# UIPickerView data (Property list)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I wanted to know if it was possible to load the data in the `didSelectRow:rowInComponent` method with a property list.

Example :

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSLog(@"Selected Row %ld", (long)row);
    switch(row) {
        case 0:
            self.prixAS.text = @"Choisissez votre";
            self.prixAR.text = @"destination.";
            self.prixdAS.text = nil;
            self.prixdAR.text = nil;
            break;
```

So load this data with a property list.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you be clearer about what you want, what you expect, giving maybe example?

Comment: @Larme I want to be able to load the data of the UIPicker with a property list. But not the data in the viewDidLoad method. I have data that change if case 0 or 1 or etc (see source code up) is selected and I wanted to know if it was possible to load this data from a property list.

Answer (score 0):

The data to show in a picker is retrieved using the delegate protocol:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

or

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

How you retrieve the data (from a static array, property list, etc...) is up to you.
There is no existing API method to load the names from a property list.